# Encrypted communication C# <-> PHP using RSA and AES

Tags: c#, php, rsa

I need an encrypted communication between C# and PHP and unfortunately can't use modules like OpenSSL on server-side. I found RSACryptoServiceProvider and [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38739/RSA-Private-Key-Encryption).

It is said that I can't use the RSACryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt something, so there is an own implementation in the article. But I found provider.Encrypt(...) and provider.Decrypt(...), so why not?

If I have something to use RSA in C#, I thought about something like this:
If php wants to send some data:

- php sends its public key to C#
- C# encrypts an key for AES with the public key from php and sends it to php
- php encrypts its message with AES and sends it to C#

(and backwards it's more or less the same)
Would that be possible or is there any security problem on this?

Comment: Just because you can't use openssl doesn't mean you can't do RSA. You can use, for example, http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is a classic method, with one important caveat: Unless you somehow verify the public key of the receiver (PHP), you are vulnerable to [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

E.g.:

- PHP sends its public key to C#
- an attacker intercepts this message
- the attacker generates and sends *his own* public key to C#
- C# encrypts a key for AES with the received key and sends it back, presumably to PHP, but, in fact, to the attacker in the middle
- the attacker receives and decrypts (using his own private key) the AES key, re-encrypts it using the public key he received from PHP, and sends it to PHP
- PHP encrypts its message with AES and sends it to C#
- the attacker intercepts the encrypted message and is able to decrypt it, as he knows the AES key

To counter that, you need to be sure the public key does belong the PHP, not to anyone else. To do that, various methods are used in practice, most commonly, [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure), i.e. instead of just the public key, you send a [*certificate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate), which is basically a public key signed by a [certification authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (i.e. a well-known entity with a known public key) that guarantees the owner of the public key.

And regarding your first question: It is definitely possible to encrypt/decrypt messages directly using RSA, there are only technical and performance reasons (AES is much faster than RSA) why RSA is used only to encrypt a session key and AES is used to encrypt/decrypt the messages themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I also understand why SSL uses certificates.

Comment: With SSH you have the key pre-cached and just verify that the public key the server is providing you with is the same one you have on file. If it isn't a popup or something appears saying as much.